# Is it possible to reduce the Groovy code for enabling and disabling testcase?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Can someone help me reduce the following code where I'm disabling and then enabling `TestCases` in `SoapUI`?

```
def totalTestCases2 = testSuite2.getTestCaseCount();
for(n in (0..totalTestCases2-1)) {
    if (testSuite2.getTestCaseAt(n).getTestStepByName("Report1"))
    {       testSuite2.getTestCaseAt(n).getTestStepByName("Report1").setDisabled(false) 
    }
    if (testSuite2.getTestCaseAt(n).getTestStepByName("Groovy_Check"))
    {   testSuite2.getTestCaseAt(n).getTestStepByName("Groovy_Check").setDisabled(false)
    }    
}
```

Comment: first extract `testSuite2.getTestCaseAt(n)` (var or `with{}`); next do your check there over a list `['Report1', 'Groovy_Check'].each{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't check it but maybe try:

```
['Report1', 'Groovy_Check'].each { name ->
   (0..totalTestCases2 - 1).findAll { cnt -> testSuite2.getTestCaseAt(cnt).getTestStepByName(name) }.each { it.setDisabled(false) }
}
```

// However this is not the best idea it twice iterates over `totalTestCases2`

Alternative:

```
testSuite2.testCaseList.each{ tc ->
    ['Report1', 'Groovy_Check'].findResults{ tc.getTestStepByName(it) }*.setDisabled(false)
}
```

Comment: the last one should be `findResults` and should return the testCaseAt (or nil)?  otherwise the index is feeded into each.

Comment: Didn't know about `findResults`. Could You please edit, not sure if I caught the idea?

Comment: done, yet i dont think that OP's "let's offshore my copy and paste mess" behaviour should be supported...